# Missing Sunday on October 25th 2020 calendar

Tags: calendar

As you can see in the following image, my calendar is missing a sunday and all dates get shifted one position afterwards (even in 2021).

I checked with other computer an it seems happens only to me... anyone knows how to fix it? :(

Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)

```
$ apt-cache policy tzdata
tzdata:
  Instalados: 2019c-0ubuntu0.18.04
  Candidato:  2019c-0ubuntu0.18.04
  Tabla de versión:
 *** 2019c-0ubuntu0.18.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2018d-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

[image: Missing sunday]

But if I click on 25th of October, even when it is shown in the "Monday" column (L) it reads "Sunday" on top left:

[image]

```
$ cal -d 2020-10
    Octubre 2020      
do lu ma mi ju vi sá  
             1  2  3  
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Thank you!

Comment: This must be a bug. It's the day that European Summer Time ends. In addition to your OS/release details, please add the output of `apt-cache policy tzdata` to your question.

Comment: @Jos : updated the question. It seems it is some problem with my installation. I came from updates from previous versions, but in new installations does not happen

Comment: Just curious: is Sunday the 25th also missing if you enter the ancient `cal -d 2020-10` command?

Comment: @Jos: `cal -d 2020-10` looks right: 25th is shown in Sunday

Comment: It does look like a bug in tzdata though, and although very interesting, bugs are offtopic here. You could sign up for a Launchpad account and report this bug to the maintainers: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+filebug, including all the above information.

Comment: @Jos : Thank you!! :)

Comment: You might want to link the bug report here when you opened it.